# Clob transformer not working in DIH

Tags: solr, lucene, transform

I am using solr 5.4.1. Here I am using dataimport handler to index data with SQL Server.

I am using CLOB transformer to convert clob value to string. Indexing is working fine but clob transformation is not working. Expected string value is not coming for clob column. There is no error or exception coming in log.

Here is the configuration:

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <datasource name="one" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Dictionary;"    user="sa"    password="xxxxxxxx" batchSize="5" />  
  <document> 
    <entity name="TestEntity" query="SELECT id, rules FROM tag" transformer="ClobTransformer">
      <field column="Id" name="id"  />
      <field column="rules" name="rules"  clob="true"/>
    </entity>
  </document>  
</dataConfig>
```

I tried using RegexTransformer, it worked. But ClobTransformer is not working. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<entity name="TestEntity" transformer="ClobTransformer" query="SELECT id, rules FROM tag" >

<field column="RULES" name="RULES" clob="true" sourceColName="RULES" />
```

REF :: [ClobTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ClobTransformer)

**It's work with me**

try to set **RULES** in upper case